# Configuration Key Value Store

Tags: perl, configuration-files, yaml, key-value

I'm in the planning stages of a script/app that I'm going to need to write soon. In short, I'm going to have a configuration file that stores multiple key value pairs for a system configuration. Various applications will talk to this file including python/shell/rc scripts.

One example case would be that when the system boots, it pulls the static IP to assign to itself from that file. This means it would be nice to quickly grab a key/value from this file in a shell/rc script (ifconfig `evalconffile main_interface` `evalconffile primary_ip` up), where `evalconffile` is the script that fetches the value when provided with a key.

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to approach this. I've tossed around the idea of using a plain text file and perl to retrieve the value. I've also tossed around the idea of using YAML for the configuration file since there may end up being a use case where we need multiple values for a key and general expansion. I know YAML would make it accessible from python and perl, but I'm not sure what the best way to access it from a quickly access it from a  shell/rc script would be.

Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3aSQLite) will give you greatest flexibility, since you don't seem to know the scope of what will be stored in there.  It appears there's support for it in all scripting languages you mentioned.

Comment: the only problem here is that it won't play nice with git and it's not quickly editable.

Comment: It's totally easy to edit the database.  Use http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/.  True, it won't play nicely with git.  You'll have to treat it as a binary file, most likely.  Guess you'll have to weigh that disadvantage against writing your own database with 4 language APIs.  =)  I think not playing nicely with Git will come out as the lesser of 2 evils.

Comment: Anothing thing I just thought of...  You could export the sqlite database as a list of sql commands for use in git.  It should merge just like a flat text file, with the disadvantage of being slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to simply do the YAML as you wanted, and then when a shell/RC wants a key/value pair, they would call a small Perl script (the `evalconffile` in your example) that would parse YAML on the shell script's behalf and print out the value(s)